# How to load to template language file (3.2)

Tags: contao

How to load to template language file in Contao 3.2?
In previous versions was like this:

```
<?php
$this->loadLanguageFile('tl_mymodule.php');
?>
```

But how is in Contao 3.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your frontend module class:

```
<?php $this->loadLanguageFile('tl_mymodule'); ?>
```

But if you want to include in the template itself,do this

```
<?php \System::loadLanguageFile('tl_mymodule'); ?>
```